# How to run Firefox from systemd service?

Tags: 22.04, firefox, snap, systemd

Can’t figure out how to fix `/system.slice/unsplashpi.service is not a snap cgroup` error.

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/unsplashpi.service
[Unit]
Description=unsplashpi
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/run.sh
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

```
$ cat /home/ubuntu/run.sh
#! /bin/bash

startx /home/ubuntu/unsplashpi.sh &> /home/ubuntu/startx.log &
```

```
$ cat /home/ubuntu/unsplashpi.sh
#! /bin/bash

DISPLAY=:0 firefox --kiosk --private-window --width 1080 --height 1920 "https://askubuntu.com" &

while :
do
  sleep 60
done
```

```
$ cat /home/ubuntu/startx.log
…
/system.slice/unsplashpi.service is not a snap cgroup
```

Comment: Running `sudo loginctl enable-linger ubuntu` solves issue but not sure it’s an elegant solution.

Comment: Are you open to using the `~/.config/autostart` directory instead of a systemd service?

Comment: Just wondering, why take the long route so the service runs under a normal user at the end? ... Won't a [user service](https://askubuntu.com/a/1475900) be a better fit for this task? ... Also It's not quiet obvious to me why `linger` would be needed in that situation, please see what's going on under the hood in a user login session regarding cgroups/scopes ...etc. https://askubuntu.com/a/1471031 which is rather too technical but might help.