# How to detach from minecraft server in ubuntu server

Tags: command-line, server, minecraft, background-process

I recently got a server and am quite new to servers in general, I'm trying to keep the server running in the background while I do other stuff on the server, any commands I try just execute as minecraft commands and ctrl+a,d doesn't work. I am running Ubuntuserver 22.04.3

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly show your entire workflow: How you launched your `screen` session, the Minecraft commands you executed within the `screen` session, and how you attempted to detach from `screen`. Don't describe; just show us both complete input and complete output of each step.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quiet sure you actually mean detach, but rather, most likely, send the running process/command to background and keep it running there while freeing up the prompt for your other commands, that can be achieved by **first**, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to **stop**(*keep this in mind*) the process while sending it to the background freeing up the prompt as a result like so (*taking e.g. `sleep 1h` as an example long running job*):

```
$ sleep 1h
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 1h
$
```

... Now that the prompt is freed up, you can **then**, resume the job in the background with `bg` like so:

```
$ bg
[1]+ sleep 1h &
$
```

... and there you have it, your job is running in the background and you can verify that with `jobs` like so:

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 1h &
$
```

... to bring it back to foreground again, use `fg` like so:

```
$ fg
sleep 1h
```

... and of course you can repeat the above steps sending it back and forth as needed.

On the other hand to detach a job from the current terminal sending it to the background to run in its own shell, run it at the first place with `& disown` like so:

```
$ sleep 1h & disown
[1] 6428
```

... but it will no longer belong to the current running shell in the current running terminal and `jobs` will not return it:

```
$ jobs
$
```

... and it will keep running [even if you close the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/1460233/968501) ... **but**, interacting with it [is not as simple anymore](https://askubuntu.com/a/1419821/968501).