# Automation/script of Bash separating, closing itself from an executable binary

Tags: bash, automation

How is script of Bash separating, closing itself from a launching of executable binary in fork, ie. form eg. $ sed & exit at the very beginning of Bash launched itself on a terminal launcher (eg. Xfce)

```
xfce4-terminal  --execute bash --rcfile ini.sh
```

That's not work, this issue may be only rare on specific case of: binary executed by binary , i.e. Wine use

Done in no script, of course as usual, will work

```
$ cat ini.sh

cd /home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/shamela4; LC_ALL=ar_SA.UTF-8 wine64 app/win/64/bin/shamela.exe & exit
```

nor with ... `&{ sleep 17; exit ;}`

it'll close altogether the Bash and the running executable binaries else
Please shed a light what actually is going on t

Comment: You might want to use `...& disown`. Please see  https://askubuntu.com/a/1460233

Answer (score 0):

You need to detach the process you want to keep running in the background after closing the terminal ... In Bash this can be done with the shell builtin [`disown`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#index-disown). So, for example; you can do something like this in the terminal:

```bash
cd /home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/shamela4; LC_ALL=ar_SA.UTF-8 wine64 app/win/64/bin/shamela.exe & disown; exit
```

... and keep your process running after closing the terminal.

For explanation, please see [Command dependent on background job finishing](https://askubuntu.com/q/1460210/968501)